# 2 ways of writing jquery, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a function, inside which are some simple expressions, adding nums, appending doms, etc.
Since I only have to call it once, so an anonymous function could do it. But which way should I choose and what's the difference?

1: Shorthand for `$(document).ready() {})` I seen this a lot,

```
$(function(){
    var something;
    ++something;
});
```

2: Found in jquery plugins. Is it binded to $(document).ready() too?

```
(function ($) {
    var something;
    ++something;
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one is *not* bound to the `ready` event.

In detail. This:

```
$(function(){  /* ... */ });
```

needs a variable `$` defined. *Usually* this variable exists when jQuery is loaded and points to the jQuery function.

Subsequently, when you call the jQuery function with a function argument, jQuery is binding this function argument to the `ready` event. The above is equivalent to

```
jQuery(function(){  /* ... */ });
```

which is in turn a convenience shorthand for

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  /* ... */ });
```

---

Your second code snippet

```
(function ($) { /* ... */ })(jQuery);
```

does *not* rely on `$` being defined or pointing to `jQuery()` (this can happen if multiple JS frameworks are loaded in parallel).

To still have the convenience of `$` within a certain region of code, it creates a function *within which* `$` is defined and points to `jQuery()`. However, it is *not* bound to a DOM event.

But this would be:

```
(function ($) { 
   $(function(){  /* ... */ });
})(jQuery);
```

This set-up is used to minimize the conflict between JS frameworks or other pieces of code that rely on `$`. jQuery plug-in authors use it to write plug-ins that work under many environments.

---

If you think the combined one is too complicated, jQuery also has a shorthand feature, which avoids variable conflicts and binds to `document ready` at the same time. But be careful, it only works on jQuery and has some downsides.

```
jQuery(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ });
```

For more details, see these two articles:

1. [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery)
2. [.ready() @ api.jquery.com (Aliasing the jQuery Namespace)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: And how about `jQuery(function($) {/*...*/});`? Does it bind a function to `document.ready()` and solve the `$` conflict issue as `(function ($) {$(function(){  /*...*/ });})(jQuery);` does?

Comment: @Rufus: Yes. `jQuery(…)` and `$(…)` are the same thing, but to avoid conflict between multiple libraries you can use the former. The main difference is that `jQuery(…)` does not define a `$` variable (i.e. you're bound to use `jQuery` throughout your code), but `function ($) {…}(jQuery)` does.

Comment: I know that `(function($){})(jQuery)` will solve the conflict issue, it pass `jQuery` as a parameter. But `jQuery(function($) {/*...*/});` seems better than `(function ($) {$(function(){  /* ... */ });})(jQuery);`, since they both solve the same issues and the former one is shorter. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NvbAW/

Comment: @Rufus: Unless I'm very much mistaken, these two forms are not equivalent. `jQuery(function($) {…})` *declares* an `$` argument, but it is never actually being *defined* in this call. So either jQuery magically passes itself as the first argument and I've never heard of that, or there is an error in your statement.

Comment: Yes, they are not equivalent, but the former one is a feature of jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery . It can solve the `$` conflict issue in a simplified way, and your code is working in a more generic way.

Answer (score 3):

**First**

It's just shorthand

**Second**

You are sandboxing the use of `$` to reduce conflicts with other libraries that use the `$` shorthand.

`$` is just a shortcut for the `jQuery` variable and is being passed into the inner function of the immediately invoked function...

Example

```
var outerVar = "something";

(function innerFunc(passedVar) {

    passedVar === "something"; //true

})(outerVar);
```

`innerFunc` is executed and passed `outerVar` as its argument.

Comment: removed the reference to closure, but even the jQuery docs call it a closure...???

Comment: @Raynos Please explain this... " ...it's a best practice to pass jQuery to a self executing function (closure)... " -jQuery docs

Comment: @Raynos So are you... please **explain**

Comment: It *is* a closure; but so is every function in javascript. I agree that the wording is misleading here though. `inner function of the closure` doesn't appeal to me.

Comment: So you're just saying it's too broad a use of the word...  By `inner` I am trying to convey the functional scope.

Comment: The fact that it creates a closure is not relevant to the fact that it's an immediately invoked anonymous function. I believe the latter is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Its not really a closure unless the environment is maintained, for which you would need to return a function or object in order to accomplish. Beyond that, its just plain old javascript functional scoping. In this case, its functional scoping. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the shorthand form is functionally identical to `$(document).ready()`.

The second example is an immediately-invoked anonymous function (Thanks @Raynos for the correction: this is often called a self-invoking function; it is not one). The function is defined and executed in place, taking `jQuery` as its argument. One advantage of this approach is that variables declared within the function will not "pollute" the global (window) scope (as opposed, for example, to simply running that code outside the function). In your example, `something` is undefined outside the function.

Since `jQuery` is brought into the function as the argument `$`, `$` is guaranteed to be jQuery within the body of that function -- even in cases where other libraries are using `$` outside the function.

A useful side note: it's sometimes helpful to name "anonymous" functions. The, uh, functionality remains the same, but names can make it much easier to debug complex code.

```
(function superFunction (foo) { // naming this "superFunction"
    var something = 10;
    do_something_with( foo, something );
})(bar);
```

Comment: immediately-invoked. It does not invoke itself so it is not self-invoking. `(function foo() { foo(); })()` would be self invoking (and also infinitely recursive)

Comment: The second one gets executed right away, and has nothing to do with document.ready, right?

Comment: @Raynos, I agree that the function isn't invoking itself (obviously), and that the term isn't accurate in that sense, but it is accepted to refer to that structure as such (AFAIK). The name is meant to be understood that the function isn't invoked *separately to it's definition*, but rather as part of it. In that sense it is invoked in its own defining, and thus named self-invoked.

Comment: wouldn't all functions be programmer invoked? ;)

Comment: Rufus, yes. @Raynos, good point, of course you're right -- it's not really invoking itself. Calling it self-invoking is sloppy, although that form is often referred to as such. I'm correcting the answer.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, maybe he's writing a self-modifying machine learning system.

Answer (score 1):

1. No it isn't, it is just a shorthand
2. No it isn't. This code makes sure that $ is really jQuery and not just another javascript library

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring:

> But wait! Where's my awesome dollar sign that I know and love? It's
>   still there, however to make sure that your plugin doesn't collide
>   with other libraries that might use the dollar sign, it's a best
>   practice to pass jQuery to a self executing function (closure) that
>   maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another
>   library in the scope of its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the two styles.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // uses the real jQuery as $
  // code
});
```

The first style was used to run some code when the DOM is ready.

The second style is used to ensure `$ === jQuery` and also to make `$` a local variable (reduces lookup time by a tiny fraction)

Comment: Great, I have another issue with another js framework using `$`, which comes to conflict with jquery. Hope this may do it.